# Why I am not able to get upper half of the HTML structure?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning web scraping and tried to scrape HTML structure on my MAC, I tried using multiple libraries(Selenium, BeautifulSoup, request-html) but still I am getting just the lower half of the HTML content of all the websites.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Print the entire HTML structure
    print(soup.prettify())

else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

The output is starting from

```
</sup>
         ):
        </strong>
        <span class="country-area">
         748.0
        </span>
        <br/>
       </div>
      </div>.....
```

Comment: My guess is that it HAS printed all the results, they've just scrolled off the top of the window.

Comment: if you can't scroll output to see upper lines then maybe change console/terminal, or maybe console/terminal has some options to use bigger buffer for output (so you could scroll it)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the code works just fine.
It might be your terminal issue. there is a limit with lines you can see there

I suggest you to save the response.text in a file (for example 'scrapethissite.html') instead of printing it.
You can modify your code like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/'

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Print the entire HTML structure
    print(soup.prettify())
    with open('scrapethissite.html', 'w') as myfile:
        myfile.write(response.text)

else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the page. Status code: {response.status_c

ode}")
```

Comment: I am still facing the same issue, this is what I am getting.  Output:  </i>
        Trinidad and Tobago
       </h3>
       <div class="country-info">
        <strong>
         Capital:
        </strong>
        <span class="country-capital">
         Port of Spain
        </span>
        <br/>

Comment: after running the modified script you should check the 'scrapethissite.html' file in the root of your project instead of the terminal
It's not a good idea to check the scraped content in console 
If the content is big you can not see all of it in your console